# Autohotkey sends literal text does not read variables

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, clipboard

My case is simple and i don't know what i'm doing wrong, the tutorial is clear about this, it should work.
When i write pste i want the contents of the clipboard send as keystrokes(i'm using it to paste text in windows console that do not support ctrl+v) so far i've tried

```
:*:pste::Send, %clipboard%
:*:pste::Send %clipboard% ;no comma
:*:pste::%clipboard% 
:*:pste::clipboard
:*:pste::%Clipboard%
:*:pste::Send, %Clipboard%
:*:pste:: %clipboard%
:*:pste:: %Clipboard%
```

in every single case it writes down the text after ::
so i type
pste
and the script writes %clipboard% or Send, %Clipboard% and so forth
 if it matters im not compiling the ahk

Comment: If you got it to work, please post the solution as an answer and not an edit. I'm getting rid of the edit so you can put it as a real answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
:*:pste::
Send %clipboard%
return
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm variables are not supported in hotstrings.

Comment: You can't use them inline, but see the accepted answer to see how to use them.